# FluentWait prints a lot of warning stack traces for ignored exception in the console when I upgrade Selenium from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: scala, selenium-webdriver

I have the following method which I use intensively in my tests and which works ok with Selenium 3.0.1

```
def waitUntilVisibleByXPath(xpath:String, timeOutInMillis:Int)(implicit driver:WebDriver): Try[WebElement] ={
    val wait:FluentWait[WebDriver] = new FluentWait(driver)
      .withTimeout(timeOutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .ignoring(classOf[NoSuchElementException])
      .withMessage(s"for element to be visible and enabled by xpath: $xpath")
    val condition:ExpectedCondition[WebElement] = ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath))
    Try{wait.until(condition)}
  }
```

I've tried to upgrade Selenium to 3.1.0 version and after that I noticed a lot of stack traces similar to this one in my console when running tests:

```
Mar 28, 2017 1:41:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //a[text()='Log out'])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //a[text()='Log out']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: 'b94c902', time: '2017-02-16 12:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'POSITRON', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-66-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
```

So basically it prints a WARNING stack trace every time it polls. It's not critical of course but it really bloats the console.
Could you explain how to disable such warnings to be printed from FluentWait-s and probably point out to some rationale behind such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just set root logger level to SEVERE:

```
LogManager.getLogManager.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.SEVERE)
```

That solved problem for me.